# Access allow control origin fails with www prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery load function on my page which gets fired when a button is clicked. The url starts with http://domain.com/... Strange enough when I browse to the page by going to http://www(dot)domain(dot)com/... A access allow control origin error shows up in de console. But when I go to plain http://domain(dot)com/... all works fine when I press the button and new content gets loaded in.

```
  var loadingOverlay = $('#loadingOverlay');

$(".newsItemTitle").click(function () {
    loadingOverlay.show();
    var $target = $(this);
    $url = "include/getFunction.php?json=1&param=" + $(this).data("id") + "&function=getMainPageContent";
    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        success: function (html) {
            $(".newsItemTitle").each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            });

            $target.addClass("active");
            var text = $.parseJSON(html)['text'];

            $(".js-content").empty().append(text);
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                loadingOverlay.hide();

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.js-content-title').offset().top - 80
                }, 'slow');
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone know how I can fixed this?

Comment: maybe share a little bit of your code?

Comment: did you tried to add the absolute path to your $url variable (not the relative)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected. `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` are different origins.

There are several ways you can fix this.

1. Don't host your website on two different hostnames. Pick one of the two to be canonical and redirect from the other one to it.
2. Always use relative URLs so you are making your Ajax requests to the same origin
3. Configure the server to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers so that the two origins can share content

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error occurs with cross object resource sharing. On a server with CORS enabled the server will identify which domain names are authorised to access the data using an AJAX connection, and the javascript security model treats sub domains as different sites under CORS. I would check to make sure that CORS has not been setup to only support domain.com, if it is then add www.domain.com as authorised as well. Your hosting provider may be able to assist with this if you are with a web host which supports CORS.